# Excel VBA get a range value from visible cells after applying autofilter

Tags: vba, excel, range, visible

Is it not possible to do something simple like this to get the range value of B2?

```
crdata.Range("B2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value
```

I have applied the autofilter to filter out with the given criteria and trying to return the range of B2 as a function.

Comment: what is crdata? If B2 is visible could you not omit the specialcells part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to a Range, then use `Cells(row, column)` on this range to pick out the value that you require.  If you are using headers in the result then you may also have to use `Offset(1,0)` to address your data.  So where 'MySheet' has been defined as a Worksheet object, smething like:

```
Set rsltRng = MySheet.Autofilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
msgbox rsltRng.cells(2,2)
```